# Display Image to Browser Directly from PC source using PHP

Tags: php, image

How to get file source path from users PC when they submit their file on form like below.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Example path that I want is *file:///C:/Users/hafizul/Downloads/myimage.png*

So, I can display user image using the code below:

```
<?php
$path = 'file:///C:/Users/hafizul/Downloads/myimage.png';
header('Content-Type:image/png');
echo file_get_contents($path,FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not know where the file came from on their computer reliably, but you can send an uploaded file back to the browser as you seemed to be attempting:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
readfile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Refer to the PHP manual chapter "Handling file uploads":

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP is a server-based language, you cannot pass him parameters of a Path on the client computer: the code is executed on the server without access or knowledge of the client and its hard drive.

A better option in this case is to use JavaScript or Flash on your page to display the image, the user can review it before submitting it and actually upload it on the server.

Check here for instance for the JavaScript version:
http://teck.in/javascript-to-preview-local-image.html

Note that your code might be blocked by security measures on the site since the access of a script to the local computer filesystem might be harmful.